# How to properly dolly (move in and out from an object) in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been searching through many forums (here and elsewhere) to find how to properly zoom in on an object in OpenGL. After reading up a lot, I finally sorta figured how to use GluLookAt(). I am able to get the camera moving like I want to without any problems. I know it works because the objects disappear as it should as the camera moves in. However, I want to zoom in on the object as I pan the camera. I thought the camera position would take care of it but updating the camera position doesn't seem to help. I also tried gScalef(), but it's getting called only once when I press the 'w' key.

```
void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x,int y)
{
  if(c==27)
    {exit(0);}
  if (c=='w')
    {
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();

      float forward_x, forward_y,forward_z;
      gluLookAt(current[0], current[1], current[2],
        current[0]+center_x, current[1]+center_y, current[2]+center_z,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  
      // glScalef(1.2,1.2,1.2);
      current[0]= (current[0]- 0.1*center_x);
      current[1]= (current[1]-0.1*center_y);
      current[2]= (current[2]- 0.1*center_z);

    }

}

void Camera_rotation(int x, int y)
{
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  center_x = cos(-0.05*x)*sin(-.05*y);
  center_y = cos(-.05*y);
  center_z = sin(0.05*x)*sin(.05*y);
  eye_x = x; eye_y = 1.0,
  float new_x = x; 
  gluLookAt(current[0], current[1], current[2],
            current[0]+center_x,
            current[1]+center_y,
            current[2]+center_z,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  render();
}
```

'current' and 'center_x[yz]' are global variables. Can someone help?

Comment: Given your comments to the answer down there, you need your terminology cleared up: Zooming s camera is changing the FOV without moving the camera. What you want to achieve *is not* zooming but *dolly* the camera. A combination of zoom with dolly is also known as the Vertigo effect made popular by Alfred Hitchcock.

Comment: @datenwolf: My bad. I have never come across the word dolly before. Thank you. I guess I'll edit the quesiton header

Answer (score 3):

As long as the camera is aiming at the object you should be able to set `FOV` (Field of View) on the `Perspective Projection Matrix` to achieve zooming effect. The smaller the `FOV` the smaller the viewing area which gives the illusion of zoom.

Brilliant tutorial on the subject can be found [here](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera). It talks about zoom right at the end.

Comment: Just to clarify. In first person shooter style games when you walk towards an object is the FOV changing? I guess it would make sense, but somehow it feels like too many computations. If the camera itself sees in a conical fashion will this problem not be solved?

Comment: FOV usually stays the same throughout the game. Though I've seen some games mess around with FOV especially when you start running it gives it a nice effect. Minecraft and CoD does it.

Comment: That's the problem, I think I am facing. I mean I just want to move the camera closer to an object and see the object up close. Since the camera position is technically close to the object, it should appear larger right? That's what I don't get

Comment: Well in that case things should be even simpler. Make sure you're using `perspective projection matrix` you will also need to set `near plane` to something reeeeeally small like 0.001f. And you should be good to go.

Comment: I am so lost. Could you show me how? here's my full code : http://pastebin.com/FNqFisFh 
sorry I am asking for this to be spoon fed

Comment: Sadly I'm not as proficient with older versions of OpenGL. Though it looks like your code is missing a call to `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` and `gluPerspective(...)`. You might find [this page](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm) helpful, it even discusses zoom.

Comment: Hey! It worked. I added the projection matrix like you told and now it's working. I guess by default there's no projection matrix that's loaded or something.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution after a discussion:

In the render() function (or your display function), mention the projection matrix. This sets how your camera behaves. Code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(30.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);// FOV = 30 degrees, aspect ratio is one and I can see throughout the plane
```